# How to call this inner function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is my JS file:
ezee.se/quickfilter.js

In an external file I am calling it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="quickfilter.js"></script>

function refresh_the_list2()
{
quickfilter_mafiaafire.request_xml();
var status = document.getElementById("refre");
 status.innerHTML = 'Done! Use the above link to view the blocklist.';
}
```

but I keep getting this error:

> Error: quickfilter_mafiaafire.request_xml is not a function

How do I call it so I *don't* get that error?

Comment: You have to include `quickfilter.js` in the main HTML. You cannot include it in another JavaScript file. `<script>` is HTML, not JavaScript.

Comment: On a second thought it seems that `quickfilter_mafiaafire` is defined but it has no method `request_xml`. Make sure it has or call the right function. Check the definition of `quickfilter_mafiaafire`.

Comment: ok, got it! Just had to add a main. before the call, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, my guess would be:

```
quickfilter_mafiaafire.main.request_xml();
```

since `request_xml` is defined as a property of `quickfilter_mafiaafire.main` on line 139.